# Need help in adjusting dialog layout

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-edittext

I want to have a custom dialog like this

[Desired dialog look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDfKR.jpg)

This is what I have tried

[image]

**There are no `listView` shown in my `dialog, only editText` !**

**Code**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_task:
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
                dialog.setView(convertView);
                ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                ArrayList<ToDoList> search = new ArrayList<>();
                search.add(0,new ToDoList("")); //populate your list here
                DialogAdapter adapter=new DialogAdapter(this,search,lv);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                dialog.show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**custom_dialog**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ListView>
```

**dialog_with_edittext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/add_new_task"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Add a new task"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dateImg"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/imgdate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtText"
        android:hint="Date"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/timeImg"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/imgtime"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:hint="Date"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okBtn"
        android:background="@color/light_sky_blue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to adjust buttons in dialog and divider line disappear right?

Comment: I want listview show in the dialog like the link I sent.

Comment: check out my answer  then i have coded as your requirement.

Comment: @brahmyadigopula I used your code but my dialog looked weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the background of the EditText to `android:color/transparent` or white. This will remove the line from `EditText` so that you can have a universal line (divider)
2. Add this wherever you want divider

   ```
   <View
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="1dp"
           android:background="#aa121212" />
   ```

Comment: Do you mean i use view instead of listview?

Comment: ideally you must be using listview. but you wrote in bold that yoi dont want list view. so this is the solution.

Comment: I want listview show in the dialog exactly like the link i sent.

Comment: Where should I add View ?

Comment: after every edit text. i have designed a similar layout earlier using linear layout as parent and combination of relative layouts and divider views as child, each relative layout containing image and edit text.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in **dialog_with_edittext.xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/add_new_task"
        android:hint="Add a new task"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtText"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/imgdate"
        android:hint="Date"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/imgtime"
        android:hint="Date"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okBtn"
        android:background="@color/light_sky_blue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and to disappear the divider lines of the listview use this..

```
android:divider="@null".
```

or you can set the color to divider line.

```
android:divider="#FFCC00"
```

Comment: where should I add `android:divider="@null".`?